# How can I delete records from a table when there are foreign keys that depend on these records?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have lots of tables that have foreign keyed to a `PersonId` column. I need to delete a person from the database.

If I do a simple:

```
DELETE FROM Persons WHERE PersonId=111
```

I get an error:

> Msg 547, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
>   The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK_CIPerson". The conflict occurred in database "adb", table "CI", column 'Person_Id'.

I keep going "down the tree" of dependencies and delete from the roots. This has generally worked, until I got to a certain table where it won't let me delete any further. I believe I have to join 2 tables and delete the rows in BOTH tables that have my `PersonId` in it.

This join joins the tables in the way I want them to be joined:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.anId = Table2.someId
```

This results in a joined table that has the `PersonId` (from `Table2`). I now want to delete all the rows where `PersonId=111`, so I need a where clause plonked in too.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If this is a regular occurrence you should set up your foreign keys to `ON DELETE CASCADE`.  Then when you delete one, it will "cascade" across the other tables deleting the rest.

Comment: It is however a single sql statement per table to delete the records otherwise.

Comment: Setting up a stored procedure where you pass in the id and it runs all the statements for you might also be an alternative.

Comment: It is possible to have two tables reference each other so that you cannot delete any row. In that case you have to disable the FK temporarily. This is very rare though and it is not clear that you are in that situation.

Comment: It sounds like the table CI's Person_ID has children of its own that must be deleted before it can proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, SQL `DELETE` statement only affects one table. If you need to cascade delete, you can simplify things by using @paqogomez suggestion: just specify `ON DELETE CASCADE` option on the foreign key declaration.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 3 solutions:

### ON CASCADE DELETE

(As answered by Gerardo) If the problem is just foreign key constraints, then you can use this and deleting the person will do all the rest. But this may not always work. As usr said, there are some cases in which foreign keys are complex and mangled a bit.

### BEFORE DELETE TRIGGER

You can define a trigger and activate it BEFORE DELETE on the person table. In the trigger you can take care of the deletion of dependent rows from other tables. This is similar to the ON CASCADE DELETE, but you have a little more control over how to perform the deletion... this may solve some of those complex problems.

### STORED PROCEDURE

You can define a stored procedure with a person_id parameter. The code would be similar to the trigger's. But in stored procedures you can sometimes do some extras, like deactivating foreign keys (not sure about SQL Server though).

### DELETION SCRIPT

This is the most powerful, as you can mix DDL and SQL and do all sorts of stuff. But scripts usually have to be run manually, which might not be acceptable in your case.

Comment: +1 for explanation, thanks, ON CASCADE DELETE looks the ticket